# Can XML be documented using Doxygen, Sandcastle, or other documentation generators?

Tags: xml, xsd, doxygen, documentation-generation, sandcastle

I am currently using Sandcastle, Doxygen, and JavaDoc to generate documentation for code I have written. Is it possible to document XML schemas using these packages? If not, are there any (preferably free!) packages which can do this? I could write the documentation myself as an extra conceptual topic within Doxygen or Sandcastle, but I would rather a tool did it for me!

An example would be (although I am no expert at XML Schema!):

```
/// <summary>Top Node</summary>
<xs:element name="TopNode">
    /// <summary>Child Node</summary>
    <xs:element name="ChildNode" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tool that I know of that can document XML schemas is [DocFlex/XML XSDDoc](http://www.filigris.com/products/docflex_xml/xsddoc/). Quite frankly, I don't have much experience using it but for what little use I did have of it, it did a pretty good job.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like just the sort of package I am after!

Answer (score 2):

I've just started using [XML Schema Documenter](http://xsddoc.codeplex.com/) which integrates with [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) and its a great combination for my needs which are a .NET plugin framework that has XML based configuration.